# Does Visual Studio has a Template to create Interface file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I know this sounds stupid, But i never had to create an interface file in visual studio as worked in support projects mostly.I thought it must have a template but cant see one.

Comment: There should be one there.  But even if there isn't in your version for some reason, just create a class file and replace the keyword `class` with `interface`.  It's otherwise identical.

Comment: sure, so i believe template for Interface, Abstract class (Or even snippets) dont exist by default?

Comment: Where are you trying to add the file? Interface will not be an option if the location you are attempting to add to is invalid.

Comment: to the solution, tried a separate directory also and app_code as well

Comment: Is this a website or web application?

Comment: also if we need an abstract class, i guess we need to mark it as one...no default template for that too?

Answer (score 0):

Create an example and use the option in the file menu option to create as a template.

Look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247121.aspx for more options.

Comment: sure, so i believe template for Interface, Abstract class (Or even snippets) dont exist by default?

Comment: Not by default. Creating a class and then tweaking by either adding or replacing a single word covers all these options so is arguably not enough effort to merit needing specific templates, especially when start considering that you might then want access modifiers and structure too. As for snippets, add snippet designer from extensions and updates. That will give you options to create your own snippets.